# Decoding smart trasport data in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In my project we have some API methods which use something called as smart transportation ( it loads huge amounts of data from the service).

I am building my Jmeter test plan to test this feature but not sure how to decode this data in  jmeter

this is how the response in Jmeter looks like

AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAGAQAAAA5EYXRhVGFibGVCZWdpbgsAAQAAAP////8BAAAAAAAAAAYBAAAADERhdGFUYWJsZUVuZAsAAQAAAP////8BAAAAAAAAAAYBAAAADkRhdGFUYWJsZUJlZ2luCwABAAAA/////wEAAAAAAAAABgEAAAAMRGF0YVRhYmxlRW5kCwABAAAA/////wEAAAAAAAAABgEAAAAORGF0YVRhYmxl

I have asked the developers and they gave me a custom extension built for fiddler to decode this response and this extenskion works perfectly in fiddler with the decoding.

So here are my questions:

Is there somthing available for Jmeter that can solve this problem with smart transportation or is there a way I can import or use this extension in Jmeter( its built in .net framework)

Comment: So this works in Fiddler with the extension that they gave me, is there a way that I can call fiddler during my test runs and assert the response in fiddler through Jmeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by importing a JAR that was custom built by the devs, I tried with the base 64 as well but did not get any consistent response

Answer (score 0):

Is it complete response? It looks pretty much like [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) but with some binary data.

You can try doing the following on your service response:

1. Add a [Beanshell Post Processor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) as a child of the request which returns the data for decoding
2. Use the following code in the Post Processor:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

   byte [] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(data);
   vars.put("DECODED", new String(bytes));
   ```
3. Use [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to view `DECODED` variable value

On data you've provided I can see several `DataTableBegin` and `DataTableEnd` strings, however the data itself isn't getting displayed. If you could post full response and query more details from developers my answer could be more comprehensive.

Comment: I tried the work around mentioned by you above and here is what I get in response of the debug sampler MeterVariables:
DECODED=°IïzZ){�¥žË
JMeterThread.last_sample_ok=true
JMeterThread.pack=org.apache.jmeter.threads.SamplePackage@1b995c8
START.HMS=132028
START.MS=1404753628431
START.YMD=20140707
TESTSTART.MS=140508728187

Comment: <a:Data>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

Comment: Since the response is really hug I am unable to post the full response here.. I asked the developers more about this and they said this is something they developed inhouse to support the huge amounts of data generated